# ReactJS: Usage of React.Fragment in Router

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, router

I'm trying to separate the Route objects from Switch. However it seems like it only loads {routes()} then, while Component1 is not loaded. In the second version (which works), they're all loaded.

Does anyone have an idea why the first code does not work and the second code does? I'm guessing it has to do with React.Fragment, what would be the alternative though?

**Doesn't work**

```
function MainContent() {
  const routes = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Switch>
        {routes()}
        <Route path="/component1" component={Component1} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Works**

```
function MainContent() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
         <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
         <Route path="/component1" component={Component1} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should check [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5785). If there isn't anything new either you should use a workaround or change your routing logic.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird. I tested the code out and the first code is working. I don't know where did you make a mistake but look at this code and see where's the actual problem.

=> https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-blackburn-tn63i

Comment: I see the difference. You didn't put {routes()} in <Switch/>, do that and you'll see Another will be broken.

Comment: How does Another even work without being in the <Switch/> object?

Comment: `Switch` is not necessary every time. This is why it works. For example, if you change the route like this in that sandbox, you can see weird behaviors. `<Route path="/:login" component={() => <p>Login</p>} />`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the issue, there isn't any direct way of doing this. You should either change the routing logic or use a workaround. [This workaround](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5785#issuecomment-359427800) is from the issue. Thanks to [bripkens](https://github.com/bripkens)

So, you can use something like this:

```
function FragmentSupportingSwitch({ children }) {
  const flattenedChildren = [];
  flatten(flattenedChildren, children);
  return React.createElement.apply(
    React,
    [Switch, null].concat(flattenedChildren)
  );
}

function flatten(target, children) {
  React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      if (child.type === React.Fragment) {
        flatten(target, child.props.children);
      } else {
        target.push(child);
      }
    }
  });
}

function MainContent() {
  const routes = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <FragmentSupportingSwitch>
        {routes()}
        <Route path="/component1" component={Component1} />
      </FragmentSupportingSwitch>
    </div>
  );
}
```